# Scale <img> inside the div

Tags: css

I have wrapping div with fixed width and height (400x300px). Inside an  with its own width/height (landscape 800x600px) or (portrait 600x800px) sometimes images can have different size. How do I scale with CSS so both can be scaled down proportionally to fit within the width or height - whichever comes first?

Here's the code:

```
<div style="width:400px; height:300px;">
    <img style="width:auto; height:auto;" src="image url>" />
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max-width and max-height:

```
img {
    max-width: 400px; 
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.your-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/tmuWY/1/).

Comment: This won't work with a 600x800 image. The vertical aspect will blow out the height of the div.

Comment: exactly i have to able scale both vertical and horizontal to fit in this frame of 400x300 without distortion

Comment: @ArturBilinski - You can set the `max-width` and `max-height` to 100%, or as @Mike Robinson said in his answer, setting these properties to the same value as the parent will work as well.